# Why does the number of votes to complete a review vary?

Tags: discussion

**Why do some posts require only one vote to handle:**

[link to review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/391382)
[image]

[link to review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/391383)
[image]

**While others require multiple votes?**

[link to review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/391122)
[image]

[link to review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/391324)
[image]

(All of these examples are from the Low Quality queue.)

---

#### Update:

**Perhaps this is a clue?  It's obvious others reviewed *this* post:**
[link to review](https://superuser.com/review/close/392519)
[image]

Comment: Only a guess: After a `delete` vote there is some form of grace period to collect more votes and it is deleted if the majority of the votes is `delete` after that period.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this sort of thing happen when moderators or trusted users hit the review queue.

Comment: @w3d If by `Trusted User` you mean someone with >10k rep, that doesn't explain the updated review I posted which included a Close vote from Ramhound who currently has 4550 rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Example 1: put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Mokubai♦
- Example 2: deleted by Mokubai♦
- Example 3: converted to a comment by Mokubai♦
- Example 4: deleted by studiohack♦
- Example 5: put on hold as too broad by ChrisInEdmonton, Ramhound, Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, Karan, Twisty

First 4 examples you can point the finger at the moderators ;)

Last example it is possible to vote as "too broad" **outside** of the review queue.

As far as I know once it gets put on hold or deleted it is removed from the queue (and is no longer reviewable).

Comment: You can obviously see data I cannot.  I suspected this might be moderator instigated.  I find it curious the review queue doesn't give some indication that the review was "cut short" for reason of moderator action...

Comment: I guess you need 10K+ to see what happended to 2, 3, and 4 as I can see the deleted answers ;) If it says "no longer reviewable" it looks like that means deleted based on your 5 data points :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools -> View deleted posts

Comment: Or, as in the case of example 2, a moderator's unilateral action, correct?  Seeing as I had been the only non-mod to review that one...

Comment: The moderator has a big hammer. No more votes are needed when the hammer hits. It depends on how many votes where already cast before the mod sees the post ...